# Locally remove a gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, equivalence-principle

Let $K$ be an inertial frame of reference on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $g=g(t,x)$ a nonuniform and nonstatic gravitational field. How I can choose a system of reference $\bar K$ such that mechanical effects of $g$ can be neglected?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of [GR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) and the [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), given a [Lorentzian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$, 
the following comments seem relevant:

1. If the (Levi-Civita) [Riemann curvature tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) does *not* vanish in a point $p\in M$, then there does *not* exist a neighborhood $U \subseteq M$ of $p$ (and a  coordinate system defined on $U$) such that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ becomes on Minkowski-form in $U$. See also my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/157019/2451).
2. Locally, there exist [Fermi normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates) along a tubular neighborhood of a geodesic.

Comment: Do you know a reference for the second fact? I've never seen that stated in that manner (tubular neighborhood).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are asking about **locally inertial frames**?

[Chapter 2.4](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/astr5770_14/grbook.pdf):

> Postulate (2) of general relativity implies that at each point of spacetime it is possible to choose locally
>   inertial coordinates:
>   $\xi^m$

Say you have coordinates $x^\mu$ and you want to transform to inertial coordinates $\xi^m$ which are in **locally inertial frame** $ds^2=\eta_{m n}\xi^m \xi^n$

The coordinates are differentiably related:

$d\xi^m=\frac{d\xi^m}{dx^\mu}dx^\mu$

Hence, you just have to find coordinates that satisfy:

$g_{\mu \nu} =\eta_{m n} \frac{d\xi^m}{dx^\mu} \frac{d\xi^n}{dx^\nu}$

*Note: last equation comes from $ds^2$=(same in every frame)*