# Riemann tensor and metric tensor second derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, equivalence-principle

I know that in general relativity, unlike in electromagnetism, the field tensor must be dependent on metric tensor second derivatives, since I can always find a reference system in which its first derivatives are null.

I don't really get this. I mean, I guess it is due to the equivalence principle that I can find a locally flat reference system so that the metric tensor is constant and its first derivatives are zero. But if they were zero, wouldn't also its second derivatives be zero?

Comment: You can't transform away intrinsic curvature.

Comment: This is explained in point 2 of my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/157019/2451).

Comment: The partial first derivatives are zero *at a point P*

Comment: It is indeed due to the equivalence principle that you can do this, but the cancellation of the first derivatives of $g$ is at *one point only*.  So it's akin to a local extremum of a function of one variable: like the curve $y=x^2$ at the point $x=0$. Move away from your special point a distance $\epsilon$ and, unless your spacetime is truly flat, the first derivatives are in general nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Example, when you throw an object straight upward, when object reach the maximum height, the displacement is constant, the velocity(first derivative) is zero, but the acceleration (second derivative) is not.